# How would I add data on a button press to the either the root or a component of Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

My main problem is that I'm trying to reactively add data to either the Vue root or a Vue component. The reason this is an issue is because once my Vue app instance is mounted, (using app.mount()), I am unable to reactively add data to the Vue application. I am trying to use Vue along with vanilla JS as I am a novice with the framework. I guess what it really comes down to is... is there any event I could trigger or object I could call in vanilla JS to insert new data into lets say an array of objects within the Vue app instance?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to install `Vuex` into your vue 3 app and inject data through vuex store.

Here is simple, plain vue3 project generated from vue-cli with command `vue create my-vue-prj`

```json
{
  "name": "my-vue-prj",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...((skipped))...
  }
}
```

And `src/main.js` entry point.

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "./store";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(store).mount("#app");

window.vueApp = app;
// or can expose store directly
// window.store = store;
```

- expose vue app instance(window.vueApp) to access from external javascript.

Vuex store can be access like this.

```
// external.js
const store = window.vueApp.config.globalProperties.$store
/*
 * can inject(modify, delete, etc) data into vue app through `store`
 */
```

## Demo

An array is defined in vuex store like this

```js
// file : src/store/index.js
import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    nums: [0, 1, 2],
  },
  mutations: {
    replaceNum(state, nums) {
      state.nums = nums;
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

- Array `nums` want to be render in `App.vue`

Array `nums` can be accessed from component `App.vue`.

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(n, index) in $store.state.nums" :key="index">{{ n }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

- `$store.state.nums` is array of [0, 1, 2]
- li is rendered with text (0, 1, 2)

Array nums can be updated from external js

```js
// external.js
const store = window.vueApp.config.globalProperties.$store
store.commit('replaceNum', [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]);
```

- `commit('replaceNum', ...)` - call method `replaceNum` in mutations. It updates `nums` and contents is also refreshed.